# Xamarin Forms: How to parse data from a local JSON file?

Tags: json, parsing, xamarin.forms

I have a local JSON file. I need to parse data from that file based on the date.

**Data format in JSON file:**

```
{"01-01-2017":{"color":"white","message":"The Octave Day of Christmas Solemnity of the Blessed Virgin Mary, the Mother of God Lectionary: 18"},"02-01-2017":{"color":"white","message":"Memorial of Saints Basil the Great and Gregory Nazianzen, Bishops and Doctors of the Church Lectionary: 205"},"03-01-2017":{"color":"white","message":"Christmas Weekday Lectionary: 206"},"04-01-2017":{"color":"white","message":"Memorial of Saint Elizabeth Ann Seton, Religious Lectionary: 207"},"05-01-2017":{"color":"white","message":"Memorial of Saint John Neumann, Bishop Lectionary: 208"},"06-01-2017":{"color":"white","message":"Christmas Weekday Lectionary: 209"},"07-01-2017":{"color":"white","message":"Christmas Weekday Lectionary: 210"},"08-01-2017":{"color":"white","message":"The Epiphany of the Lord Lectionary: 20"},"09-01-2017":{"color":"white","message":"The Baptism of the Lord Lectionary: 21"},"10-01-2017":{"color":"darkseagreen","message":"Tuesday of the First Week in Ordinary Time Lectionary: 306"}}
```

Based on the date I need to parse the corresponding message. How I can do this?

Comment: If you print in the console the variable `jsonString` what do you see? Do it before calling `JObject.Parse(jsonString);`

Comment: I test the code you provided, no error, it works perfectly. Could you provide code sample for me to test?

Comment: @pinedax Problem was with my JSON file. It contains some special charactors.

Comment: @WendyZang Problem was with my JSON file. It contains some special charactors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Added JSON file to PCL project, and set Build Action to Embedded Resource.
2. Get the value based on the date.

   ```
   void GetJsonData(string date)
   {
   try
   {
       string jsonFileName = "prayers.json";
       var assembly = typeof(HomePage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

       Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");
       using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
       {
           var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

           JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

           var color = obj[date]["color"];
           var message = obj[date]["message"];
       }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("PrayerException:>"+e);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Can't accept on answers for a time period, now accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First make class for your specific data:

```
public class JsonContent{
    public string color {get; set;}

    public string message {get; set;}
}
```

Then make List of Dictionary:

```
List<Dictionary<DateTime,JsonContent>> jsonData = new List<Dictionary<DateTime, JsonContent>>();
```

Parse your data to variable:

```
jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<DateTime, JsonContent>>>(yourJSON);
```

Now u have all data:

```
foreach (var item in jsonData)
{
    //your date - item.key;
    //your data inside - item.color and item.message
}
```

Im not sure it will work :)